# I was trying to implement QuickSort but getting garbage array elements as output

Tags: c++, data-structures, quicksort

This is my partition logic for quick sort, and it is providing me          Garbage array element values as error. I think I am mistaken with my partition code but also i am not sure about that.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(int* x, int* y)
{

    int temp = *y;
    *y = *x;
    *x = temp;
}

int partition(int* A, int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = A[left];
    int i = left + 1, j = right;
    while (i <= j) {
        if (A[i] <= pivot)
            ++i;
        if (A[j] > pivot)
            --j;
        if (A[i] > pivot && A[j] <= pivot) {
            swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }
    swap(&A[left], &A[j]);
    return j;
}

void quickSort(int* A, int left, int right)
{

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    int pi = partition(A, left, right);
    quickSort(A, left, pi - 1);
    quickSort(A, pi + 1, right);
}

int main()
{

    int A[] = { 5, 8, 1, 31, 2, 44, 6, 0, 8, 4 };
    int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    quickSort(A, 0, n - 1);
    for (auto i : A)
        cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Why are you passing pointers to `std::swap`?

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop you are using 3 separate `if` statements. All 3 will be potentially executed on every iteration before checking than `i <= j`. In the second call to `partition` this results in `j` being set to `-1`, from this point on your code writes lots of values out of bounds of the array causing stack corruption and a crash or at least an incorrect result.

Adding `else` solves the problem:

```
while (i <= j) {
    if (A[i] <= pivot)
        ++i;
    else if (A[j] > pivot)
        --j;
    else if (A[i] > pivot && A[j] <= pivot) {
        swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
}
```

Note that [choosing the first element as the pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) results in worst case performance for quick sort when the array is already sorted, generally the mid point is a better choice.

Unrelated to your problem but see also:

[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Having a function with the same name as a function in the standard library (`swap`) combined with importing the whole of the standard library via `bits/stdc++.h` and bringing the whole standard library into the global namespace via `using namespace std` is likely to lead to ambiguous overload errors.

Comment: thanks a lot Alan, I saw your profile you are a C++ Developer and that's too good. I also want to be a C++ Developer could you please help me by providing some suggestions about which technologies i should learn and which features I must learn to be a developer.

Comment: Learning to use a debugger is a key skill for any programmer